# MySQL Connector/C++ in Xcode 9.2 via Homebrew usage problems

Tags: c++, homebrew, mysql-connector, xcode9.2, mysql-connector-c

I've successfully installed MySQL, Boost and mysql-connector-c++ on my macOS High Sierra 10.13.3 via Homebrew, but i've ran into problems with using those libs in Xcode.

So, my boost and connector libs are located at `/usr/local/Cellar/`. So i just wrote a simple code sample to check if everything "works":

```
#include <mysql_driver.h>
#include <mysql_error.h>
#include <mysql_connection.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

and compiled it with

```
c++ -I /usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-
c++/1.1.9_1/include/mysql_connection.h /usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-
c++/1.1.9_1/include/mysql_driver.h /usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-
c++/1.1.9_1/include/mysql_driver.h main.cpp
```

Everything seems to be working, except I get some warnings:

> clang: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, 
>       this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
>
> clang: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, 
>   this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]

But that's not a huge issue, I think.
And then I try to use those libs in Xcode, so i do this:

[image: Xcode 9.2 build settings]
Yet when I try to compile any code with those libs in Xcode, I get this:

> 'boost/scoped_ptr.hpp' file not found with  include; use "quotes" instead'

and many errors alike for boost and mysql-connector-c++. Obviosly, changing all <> to "" in source files is NOT a good idea, futhermore, it's extremely tiring.

How to fix this error?